# How to fixed TEXT center in HTML css

Tags: html, css

i have image and text like this image
[image]

When width logo image is correct Text is center , its is work

But when i have image box shape like bellow
[image]

**TEXT not center**, how to fixed text center without deppends image width ??

this is my code..

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb4" style="display: flex; display: -webkit-box;margin-top:30px; ">
                    <th><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % to_text(logo)"/></th>
                    
                      <h4 style="margin-top:60px;margin-left:140px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;width:600px;text-align:center;"><th><span t-esc="nama_ou"/></th> </h4>    
                    <!-- <h4 style="max-width:450px;margin-left:500px;overflow-wrap: break-word;font-size:30px;"> <th><span t-esc="operating_unit"/></th> </h4> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 text-right" style="margin-top:22px;" name="moto"/>
            </div>
```

Plis help, i stack about this, Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: I would suggest to set image in position absolute to the left.

Comment: You seem to be mixing Bootstrap classes with explicit styles. If you're using Bootstrap, it makes more sense to use its built-in utility classes like `text-center`. Also, you're using orphan `th` blocks - these should only be used within a `table` structure, which this isn't. Finally, I'd advise you to use your browser's Inspector tool to see what's happening. Right-click and choose "Inspect element", and you'll see lots of info about position, width, padding etc.

Comment: Try this `display: flex;  justify-content: center;`

Comment: this is print pdf , not browser , can not inspect element broo

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in your html structure. Use below html and check it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mb4" style="display: flex; display: -webkit-box;margin-top:30px; ">
        <div><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % to_text(logo)"></div>
    
        <h4 style="margin-top:60px;margin-left:140px;font-size:40px;font-weight:bold;width:600px;text-align:center;">
            <span t-esc="nama_ou">  
        </h4>    
        <!-- <h4 style="max-width:450px;margin-left:500px;overflow-wrap: break-word;font-size:30px;"> <th><span t-esc="operating_unit"></th> </h4> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 text-right" style="margin-top:22px;" name="moto"></div>
</div>
```